# Assignment of functions before entering a for-loop in Python

Tags: python, numpy

In the following example code I want to replace patches of size `ps x ps` in a lot of images with zeros, ones or random numbers. Here is an example:

[image]

To keep the for-loop clean, fast and the python script short, I wanted to define a function `patch_fct` before entering the for-loop, which does the job. Unfortunately the functions `np.zeros` and `np.ones` differ in such a way from `np.random.rand` and `np.random.randn` that they take different arguments to define the size of the output. For a 2x2 matrix I do the following to get a matrix with ones:

```
np.ones((2,2))
```

and I do

```
np.random.rand(2,2)
```

if I want a matrix with random numbers.

Here is a fully working example code. If I use `patch_fct((ps,ps))` in the for-loop, it only works for "ones" and "zeros". In order to work for random numbers, I have to change that line to `patch_fct(ps,ps)`.

Is there a way to do this anyway?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

n_images = 100
w_size = 30

h_size = 30
patch_type = "ones"
ps = 4

images = -np.ones((n_images, h_size, w_size))
x0 = np.random.randint(0, w_size - ps, n_images)
y0 = np.random.randint(0, h_size - ps, n_images)

if patch_type == "zeros":
    patch_fct = np.zeros
elif patch_type == "ones":
    patch_fct = np.ones
elif patch_type == "rand":
    patch_fct = np.random.rand
elif patch_type == "randn":
    patch_fct = np.random.randn
else:
    raise "Error patch type"

for i, x, y, x1, y1 in zip(range(n_images), x0, y0, x0 + ps, y0 + ps):
    images[i, x:x1, y:y1] = patch_fct((ps,ps)) # <-- PROBLEM:

for k in range(25):
    plt.subplot(5,5,k+1)
    plt.imshow(images[k])
    plt.axis("off")
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**There are pre-defined functions that take tuples:**

Read the docs, for `np.random.rand`:

> This is a convenience function. If you want an interface that takes a shape-tuple as the first argument, refer to `np.random.random_sample` .

---

And for `np.random.randn`:

> This is a convenience function.  If you want an interface that takes a tuple as the first argument, use `numpy.random.standard_normal` instead.